# "Failure installing dependencies" when installing Helm with Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am currently trying to install [helm](http://helm-engine.org/) with [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack). I created a simple project with

```
stack new sandbox
```

and added helm as a dependency on `sandbox.cabal`:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , helm
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

After that I run the usual `stack build` and get the error, indicating that I have to add `helm-0.7.1` on my `stack.yaml` file. I do that and also insert `elerea-2.8.0`, since it was also a requirement.
This is my `stack.yaml`:

```
# Specifies the GHC version and set of packages available (e.g., lts-3.5, nightly-2015-09-21, ghc-7.10.2)
resolver: lts-3.12

# Local packages, usually specified by relative directory name
packages:
- '.'

# Packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps:
- helm-0.7.1
- elerea-2.8.0

# Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
flags: {}

# Extra package databases containing global packages
extra-package-dbs: []

# Control whether we use the GHC we find on the path
# system-ghc: true

# Require a specific version of stack, using version ranges
# require-stack-version: -any # Default
# require-stack-version: >= 0.1.4.0

# Override the architecture used by stack, especially useful on Windows
# arch: i386
# arch: x86_64

# Extra directories used by stack for building
# extra-include-dirs: [/path/to/dir]
# extra-lib-dirs: [/path/to/dir]
```

Running `stack build` again gives me this error.

```
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      helm: needed (-any), couldn't resolve its dependencies
    needed for package: sandbox-0.1.0.0

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      cairo: needed (>0.12 && <0.13), 0.13.1.0 found (latest version available)
      mtl: needed (>=2.1 && <2.2), 2.2.1 found (latest version available)
      pango: needed (>0.12 && <0.13), 0.13.1.0 found (latest version available)
      sdl2: needed (>=1.1 && <1.3), 1.3.1 found (latest is 2.1.0)
      time: needed (>=1.4 && <1.5), 1.5.0.1 found (latest version available)
    needed for package: helm-0.7.1
```

What does this error mean? From what I understand it is not finding the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

What it's saying is that the stackage resolver you are trying to use (lts-3.12) is incompatible with helm-0.7.1.

For instance, helm-0.7.1 requires a cairo version between 0.12 and 0.13, but the version of cairo supported in lts-3.12 is 0.13.1. Similarly for the other constraints.

It is possible that the helm might actually work with a later version of cairo. To test that, download the helm source, modify the dependency in its cabal file and include it in your stack project as a local package.

Another suggestion is to see if it builds in a cabal sandbox.

Comment: oh, ok. So if I lower the stackage resolver it should work?

Comment: Not necessarily. Even 2.x resolvers use cairo >= 0.13. Ideally the maintainers would add helm to stackage so they can be notified when they need to adjust the dependency bounds.